# Paste and Match Style in Safari not working in Google Apps (Slides/Docs etc)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-slides

I've been using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Chrome and Firefox for a while now, but now that both Chrome and Firefox are giving me lots of issues with my tablet and other Slides functions I've swapped back to Safari and I'm loving it.

**But**, the Paste and Match Style isn't working anymore. I've tried everything, removing AdBlock Plus (as suggested for Firefox), I've tried creating a hotkey in Keyboard specifically for the Safari App and matching the new combo, and I've also tried the proper Combo for Safari (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and still no results.

Has anyone had any issues? I've restored to default my keyboard as well just to be sure. Still nothing.

Halp?

Comment: Same problem here.

Command + Option + Shift + V works with safari in google docs
The same does not work for google chats (nothing is pasted).

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: The OP stated in his post that it's not working for him.

Answer (score -1):

Command + Option + Shift + V works